# TreeView keeps adding content after button click

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0

I am working in a ASP website. I am inserting data to a TreeView dynamically using some table from SQL Server. I want to add a feature, which use a button to create a new child-node.
The problem is that when I click the button the page seems to 'refresh' and then it add again the content which was already populated when the page loaded. **I have get the solution for this, using the IsPostBack inside the PreRender**. **However, I need to click the button twice to open a popup window to enter the name of the child-node.**

Searching over Google, said that I need to use the !IsPostBack, or the PreRender method for the TreeView. However, neither of these methods worked for me. Below is my code,

```
<div id="content">
<div class="post">
<h1 class="title"> <asp:Label ID="lblTitle" runat="server" Text="Documents"></asp:Label></h1>

    <div class="entry" >

     <!-- Center the pop window in the middle -->
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function PopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
                var left = (screen.width / 2) - (w / 2);
                var top = (screen.height / 2) - (h / 2);
                var targetWin = window.open(pageURL, title, 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
            } 
        </script>

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="PopupCenter('NewFolderPopup.aspx', 'Add Document',340,185);">Click Here for Upload</a>
        <font size="4">

        <asp:TreeView ID="TreeViewDocuments" runat="server" ExpandDepth="0" 
            ImageSet="Simple" Visible="False" onprerender="TreeView_PreRender">
            <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" />
            <LeafNodeStyle NodeSpacing="10px" />
            <Nodes>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="System" Value="Systems" Expanded="False" 
                    SelectAction="Expand">
                </asp:TreeNode>
                <asp:TreeNode Text="Document" Value="Documents" Expanded="False" 
                    SelectAction="Expand">
                </asp:TreeNode>
            </Nodes>
            <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="Medium" ForeColor="Black" 
                HorizontalPadding="0px" NodeSpacing="7px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
            <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
            <SelectedNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#5555DD" 
                HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
        </asp:TreeView>

            <asp:Button ID="btnNewFolder" runat="server" Text="New Folder" 
            onclick="btnNewFolder_Click" UseSubmitBehavior="False"/>
            <asp:Button ID="btnRenameFolder" runat="server" Text="Rename Folder" />
            <asp:Button ID="btnDeleteFolder" runat="server" Text="Delete Folder" />
   </font></div>

</div>
```

Code behind,

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            if (!HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
                TreeViewDocuments.Visible = false;
                lblTitle.Text = "You need to be logged in.";
            }
            else
                TreeViewDocuments.Visible = true;
    }
    protected void TreeView_PreRender(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
           AddNewNode();
        }
    }
    // Some Code to pop 
     protected void AddNewNode()
     {
      ...
     }
    .
    .
    .
    protected void btnNewFolder_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TreeViewDocuments.Nodes[0].ChildNodes[0].Checked)
        btnNewFolder.Attributes.Add("onclick", "PopupCenter('NewFolderPopup.aspx', 'Add Folder',340,125);");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you should call AdNewNode() when button is clicked.

In your case, when button is clicked, the refresh happens and the new row is added again and again. But it is added even without click, no?

**EDIT**:

This line:

```
btnNewFolder.Attributes.Add("onclick", "PopupCenter('NewFolderPopup.aspx', 'Add Folder',340,125);");
```

You should put it inside the pre-render but not click.

Comment: The problem is that if I put the function inside the button click, the whole nodes will be created as times as the user click create single new node. Also, I don't know why I need to click the button twice to get it work.

Comment: Hi, I used this before see your post :     <pre>Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page.GetType(), "", "targetWin = window.open('NewFolderPopup.aspx', 'Add Folder', 'toolbar=0, location=0, directories=0, status=0, resizable= 0, menubar=0, copyhistory=no, width=460, height=150');  targetWin.moveTo((screen.height / 2) - (150/ 2), (screen.width / 2) - (460 / 2));", true);</pre>

Then I did what you mention and works too. Thanks!